# Is it possible to use an alloy-ui module with the YUI seed?

Tags: alloy-ui

We are using YUI extensively and would like to use a few of the alloy-ui widgets. E.g. the diagram builder.

If we include the original YUI seed, can we load and use alloy-ui modules?

I am assuming this would be possible using groups in the YUI config, but how painful is this going to get? Is there a recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Would really love to know how this works too. AlloyUI has some nice components, but it's a shame that they have their own seed file and what not, rather than publishing those components as gallery modules.

Comment: @F21 since YUI is now dead, I believe AlloyUI will be switching to another JS foundation. So don't keep your hopes up.